# How to simulate a left join on php array merge?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to simulate an inner join for 2 arrays in php.

How do I do that?

I have these arrays:

```
$parents = [
    0 => ['parent_id' => 1, 'data1'],
    1 => ['parent_id' => 2, 'data2'],
    2 => ['parent_id' => 3, 'data3'],
];

$children = [
    1 => [
        ['parent_id' => 1, 'children 1'],
        ['parent_id' => 1, 'children 2'],
        ['parent_id' => 1, 'children 3'],
    ],
    2 =>[
      ['parent_id' => 2, 'children 11'],
      ['parent_id' => 2, 'children 22'],
      ['parent_id' => 2, 'children 33'],
    ]
];
```

And the result should be:

```
$result = [
    0 => ['parent_id' => 1, 'data1', 'children 1'],
    1 => ['parent_id' => 1, 'data1', 'children 2'],
    2 => ['parent_id' => 1, 'data1', 'children 3'],
    3 => ['parent_id' => 2, 'data2', 'children 11'],
    4 => ['parent_id' => 2, 'data2', 'children 22'],
    5 => ['parent_id' => 2, 'data2', 'children 33'],
    6 => ['parent_id' => 3, 'data3'],
];
```

I tried this code:

```
$result = [];

foreach ($parents as $id => $parent) {
if (!isset($children[$id])) {
    $result[] = $parent;
    continue;
}
foreach ($children[$id] as $child) {
    $result[] = array_merge($parent, $child);
}
}

print_r($result);
```

But I was hoping there is a better way to do this.
Is there any php function that does that?

Thanks!

Comment: Assuming you mean to mimic a SQL inner join, then your result is wrong because you wouldn't get any results for parent_id 3. Currently this is a left join

Comment: yes, a left join I want to simulate